# Round up to the nearest 500 or 1000 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Round *UP* to the nearest 100 in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204412/round-up-to-the-nearest-100-in-sql-server)

Is it possible to round up a figure to the nearest 500 or 1000 in SQL Server?

Example:

14425.00 -> 14500.00
14585.00 -> 15000.00

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204412/round-up-to-the-nearest-100-in-sql-server

Comment: It's different, because it doesn't want to round **up**, always.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use this, with data by example

```
declare @num int
set @num = 749
select (round(((@num+250)/500),0)*500)
Result = 500
```

or to show it works

```
declare @num int
set @num = 750
select (round(((@num+250)/500),0)*500)
Result = 1000
```

however wrapping into a general function would be sensible

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufnRoundMyValue 
(
    @val int,
    @base int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    declare @res int

    select @res = (round(((@val+(@base/2))/@base),0)*@base) 
    RETURN @res
END
GO
```

then it's just

```
select dbo.ufnRoundMyValue(749,500)
```

wherever you need it

Answer (score 1):

Always rounding up:

```
((value+499)/500)*500
```

Rounding up or down:

```
((value+250)/500)*500
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT (((col+250)/500)*500) FROM table;
```